# C# Determine if a char at index is between two characters in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

In C# how do I determine if a char at a certain index is between two characters in a string. I'm trying to do this to remove all spaces between quotes in a string.
Example syntax: isBetween(string str, int index, char start, char end)

Thanks in advance

Edit: I also need it to work if start and end are the same character

Edit2: To clarify, I need it to work not only directly between, but it needs to work for other strings like isBetween("as((sup)hello)as", 5, '(', ')')

Comment: Can you show what's your desired result with an example?

Comment: `(substring(int start, int end)).Contains(char);` would be a way, after you figured out the indexes. Note that in .NET, single chars are automatically cast into very short strings and most. | But I think Regex could that even better, down to just giving you the part of the string you want. But I never fully learned the regex syntax.

Comment: Let me rewrite your question. You want to see if `start` char occurs before that index, and if `end` char occurs after that index? Is that it? The problem is that is quite a different task than "removing all spaces between quotes in a string". My naive way of doing that would be to construct a new string (using StringBuilder) by appending characters, one by one, tracking when I enter and leave quoted areas, and skipping spaces inside. However, even so, my rewrite at the start should give you some ideas about how to implement your way. **Basically, you have a X/Y problem. Solve X, not Y.**

Comment: `result = str.ElementAtOrDefault(index - 1) == start && str.ElementAtOrDefault(index + 1) == end;`

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE], some use cases ans some test cases (with input and output)?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information given, and from what I understand about your question, you want an extension method for strings.

Something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var isBetween = "abc".IsBetween(1, 'a', 'c');
        Console.WriteLine(isBetween); //True
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this String str, int index, char start, char end)
    {
        var left = str[index - 1];
        var right = str[index + 1];
        return left == start && right == end;
    }
}
```

The code above will check if the character at index 1 (which is `b`), is between two characters (`a` and `c`). This returns true.

(Note that this does not account for index out of bound exceptions)

Comment: `IndexOutOfRangeException` incomming

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Not directly between, it needs to work for other strings like isBetween("as((sup)hello)as", 5, '(', ')')

Answer (score 1):

what I understood form your question. you are looking for something like this.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main()
    {
      var isBetween = "abc".IsBetween('b', 'a', 'c', out int i);
      Console.WriteLine(isBetween); //True
      Console.WriteLine(i); //True
    }
  }

  public static class Extensions {
    public static bool IsBetween(this String str, char middle, char start, char end, out int index)
    {
      index = - 1;
      var left = str.IndexOf(start);
      var right = str.IndexOf(end);
      index = str.IndexOf(start) + 1 == str.IndexOf(end) -1 ? str.IndexOf(end) - 1: -1 ;
      return str[index] == middle ;

    }
  }
```

@ThePerplexedOne I did reuse your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using RegularExpressions [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dOFUMg)

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main()
    {
      String xs = "aBc";
      var x= xs.ReplaceInBetween('a', 'c', 'B', 'b');      }
  }

  public static class Extensions {
    public static string ReplaceInBetween(this String str,  char start, char end, char middle, char replacewith)
    {
       Regex x = new Regex($"([{start}])({middle})([{end}])");
      str=  x.Replace(str, "$1" + replacewith + "$3");
      return str;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, fro a public methid we should validate `str`, `index` and then check for chars at `index - 1`, `index + 1`:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this String str, int index, char start, char end) {
  return str != null &&                           // not null
         index >= 1 && index < str.Length - 1 &&  // valid index
         str[index - 1] == start &&               // char at index is between 
         str[index + 1] == stop;
}
```

However, if you want to *remove* some characters (say, enquoted spaces), I suggest building a new string, e.g.

```
// "abc "  123   456 789" pq" -> "abc "123456789" pq"
public static string RemoveQuotedSpaces(String str) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    return str;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);

  bool inQuotation = false;

  foreach (char c in str) {
    if (c == '"')
      inQuotation != inQuotation;

    if (!inQuotation || c != ' ') 
      sb.Append(c);
  }

  return sb.ToString();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static bool IsBetween(String str, int index, char start, char end)
{
    var startIndex = str.Substring(0, index).LastIndexOf(start);
    var LastIndex = str.Substring(index).IndexOf(end);
    if (startIndex == -1 || LastIndex == -1)
        return false;

    LastIndex = LastIndex + index;
    return startIndex <= (index - 1) && LastIndex >= (index - 1);
}
```